# How to get current activity from IME service in android

Tags: android, android-input-method

I am developing an android soft keyboard. I need to get the root view and textedit of currently active foreground activity from the IME service. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, unless you use Accessibility Service. You can get some info about TextEdit from IME.
Why do you need root view and text edit?